# SQL generate new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, rows

I have a following table:

```
ShopId  NumberOfOrders
1       2
2       3
3       2
4       0
```

Example result:

```
ShopId   OrderId
1        NULL
1        NULL
2        NULL
2        NULL
2        NULL
3        NULL
3        NULL
```

How to make a query that returns x number of rows for each Shop where x depends on NumberOfOrders?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I think he wants two rows for shopID 1, 3 rows for shopID 2 , etc...

Comment: Edited my question, Nightmaresux is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a list of numbers.  `spt_values` is one way to get a list of integers in SQL Server.  The values are probably big enough for this purpose:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as n
      from master..spt_values s
     )
select t.shopId, NULL as OrderId, n.n, t.NumberOfOrders
from following t join
     n
     on n.n <= t.NumberOfOrders
```

Note:  The CTE can also be written as:

```
      select number as n
      from master..spt_values s
      where type = 'E'
```